# Why the decorator function doesn't detect the default parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, default-value

Here is the code:

```
# Decorators
def on_or_off(func):
    def wrapper(*args, on_switch, **kwargs):
        if on_switch:
            func(*args, on_switch=on_switch, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@on_or_off
def print_101(on_switch=False):
    print ('101')

print_101()

# TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'on_switch'
```

I thought the default `on_switch` value will pass to the wrapper function, but it doesn't. How can the line `print_101()` remains the same and allows for passing the default `on_switch` value to the wrapper decorator function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_switch` is keyword-only, you declared it as such by using `*args` *before* it.

`print_101` now refers to the `wrapper` function, which is missing the `on_switch` argument, because it's required.

You can solve this by declaring its default value inside the wrapper:

```
# Decorators
def on_or_off(func):
    def wrapper(*args, on_switch=False, **kwargs):
        if on_switch:
            func(*args, on_switch=on_switch, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Theoretically, you could look into `func.__defaults__` or use the `inspect` module to automatically figure out the default value, but that's probably overkill:

```
# Decorators
def on_or_off(func):
    bindings = dict(zip(func.__code__.co_varnames, func.__defaults__))
    bindings.update(func.__kwdefaults__)
    def wrapper(*args, on_switch=bindings["on_switch"], **kwargs):
        if on_switch:
            func(*args, on_switch=on_switch, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```